# Leaflet: Markers hidden when panning map

Tags: leaflet

I've implemented a Leaflet map with a couple of different custom markers using DivIcons.

It works fine in desktop browsers, but when I pan the map on a mobile device the markers that aren't currently visible in the viewport seems to be hidden until I stop panning the map.

Is there any option for disabling this behavior? I would ideally like to keep the markers rendered all the time.

I should mention that I'm using the MarkerCluster plugin as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got this great answer on stackoverflow: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48541865/6771453

Essentially; That is the effect of Leaflet.markercluster plugin [`removeOutsideVisibleBounds`](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.markercluster#enabled-by-default-boolean-options) option.